# Complex circle box with figcaption

Tags: html, css, frontend

i'm having a problem here.

I have this circle box with a image inside and a caption in the footer of the circle:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4NjZ.png

But when i resize the window, this happen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsl0E.png

I want a fix width in the caption element, but i cant set this because the caption have a absolute position.

How can i fix that?

Code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure class="circle-image-box-with-caption">
            <img class="wow rotateIn" src="img/baresebaladas.jpg">
            <figcaption>
                <h2>ENTRADA VIP EM BARES E BALADAS</h2>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.about .col-md-4 {
    padding: 50px;
}
.about .circle-image-box-with-caption {
    position: relative;
}
.about .circle-image-box-with-caption img {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f98835; 
}
.about .circle-image-box-with-caption figcaption {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px;
    bottom: -40px;
    border: 1px solid #f98835;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    background: #f98835;
}
```

Comment: You will want to use `display:inline-block` on the `figure`to make sure it shrink-wraps the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use display:inline-block on the figure to make sure it shrink-wraps the image

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-md-4 {
  padding: 50px;
}
.circle-image-box-with-caption {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle-image-box-with-caption img {
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
  width: 254px;
  height: 254px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #f98835;
  display: block;
}
.circle-image-box-with-caption figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 20px;
  bottom: -40px;
  border: 1px solid #f98835;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #f98835;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <figure class="circle-image-box-with-caption">
    <img class="wow rotateIn" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-254-254-8.jpg" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>ENTRADA VIP EM BARES E BALADAS</h2>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, could you explain me better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-width` instead of `width` http://jsfiddle.net/nvmf9g8z/

```
.circle-image-box-with-caption figcaption {
max-width: 200px;
position: absolute;
padding: 0 20px;
bottom: -40px;
border: 1px solid #f98835;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
background: #f98835;
}
```

Comment: @Dri i don't have any other ideas